# PHP Echo is weird

Tags: php, echo

So when trying to echo an amount of money for the user it shows 0.000.000.000.00 (proof below). I store this in the database as 10,2 as a decimal. Here is the code for the echo:

```
<?php $user_details = $db->select("SELECT * FROM 'as_user_details'");
foreach ( $user_details as $row ) {
    echo $row['payout']; 
} ?>
```

Here is the link for a screenshot: https://gyazo.com/97c7cb18ea53decc7eed4e91b254f1c7

Comment: add `var_dump($user_details)` to your question

Comment: In the DB the value is as you want it?

Comment: yes in the database the numbers are how I want it but when i echo it out, it shows that funky number

Comment: Can you show what the actual value is and what `$row['payout']` is?

Comment: well in the database the default value is 0.00

Comment: So you have 4 empty rows, no? Add `<br>` at the end of that echo.

Comment: here is my phpmyadmin row https://gyazo.com/89397bbed693d1cc69ee70ccad3490d3

Comment: cant help if you dont provide information requested. good luck.

Comment: Yea, so you have 4 `0.00` values, it displays as it should... I'll refer to comment from 8 minutes ago.

Comment: you should put `echo $row['payout']."<br>"; ` instead `echo $row['payout']; `

Comment: @chris85 but what if i only wanted to show only that users amount of money??

Comment: This is sounding like an XY problem... What is the actual question here? How to query a specific record? Look up `where` clauses.. Also note `''` are for strings, backticks are for tables/columns.

Comment: i wanted to show the amount of money the user has made and not show all the users amount of money. like when echoing out a username and wanting to echo the users username only. @chris85

Comment: @LilPanda currently you select every user, you should only select the one you want in the query.

Comment: `SELECT payout FROM as_user_details where userid = ?`

Comment: so like <?php $user_details = $db->select("SELECT payout FROM 'as_user_details' where userid = ?");
foreach ( $user_details as $row ) {
    echo $row['payout']; 
} ?>

Answer (score 1):

You're simply outputting all of the values on a single line. There are no line breaks in your `echo` statement therefore it all appears in one long string. The output is correct.

This:

```
0.000.000.000.00
```

Is equivalent to:

```
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
```

Comment: what if I wanted the 0.00 to be the users amount and not show other peoples amount??

Comment: @LilPanda then select just that user, not every one, as you currently do

Comment: how would i do that

Comment: Change your SQL query. You're selecting all the results from your table. Refine the query so you're only getting the result from the user you're looking for. Look at the docs for `WHERE` clauses

Comment: i want my user to only see his payout though not everyone elses?

Comment: @LilPanda Which is precisely why you need to update your SQL query. There's a comment on your question with more of an example of what that query would look like. That should provide you with a good starting point